# Angular JS : How i can change glyphicon when i click on accordion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I want to change glyphicon glyphicon-plus by glyphicon glyphicon-minus when I click on the accordion and set the color of the active accordion. Have you an idea please for my problem.

page.chtml:

```
 <accordion>
    <spotcam class="accordion" data-ng-repeat="spot in Spots" title="{{spot.title}}">                  @Html.Partial("~/Views/Common/ConfigurationTemplateDefault.cshtml")
   </spotcam>
 </accordion>
```

Controller :

```
 .directive('accordion', function () {
          return {
              restrict: 'EA',
              replace: true,
              transclude: true,
              template: '<div data-ng-transclude=""></div>',
              controller: function () {
                  var Spots = [];
                  this.Open = function (selected_Spot) {
                      angular.forEach(Spots, function (Spot) {
                          if (selected_Spot != Spot)
                              Spot.showMe = false;
                      });
                  };
                  this.addSpot = function (Spot) {
                     Spots.push(Spot);
                  };
              }
          };
      })
      .directive('spotcam', function () {
                return {
                    restrict: 'EA',
                    replace: true,
                    transclude: true,
                    require: '^accordion',
                    scope: { title: '@' },
                    template: '<div>' +
                                '<div class="title"><a class=" more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ng-class="{ 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus': spot != 'selected_Spot', 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus' : spot == 'selected_Spot' }"  data-ng-click="toggle()"></a>{{title}}</div>' +
                                '<div class="body" data-ng-show="showMe" data-ng-transclude=""></div>'+
                                '</div>',
                    link: function (scope, element, attrs, accordionController) {
                        scope.showMe = false;
                        accordionController.addSpot(scope);
                        scope.toggle = function () {
                            scope.showMe = !scope.showMe;

                            accordionController.Open(scope);
                        };
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One option is to use the scopes variable showMe in the expression

```
template: '<div>' +
            '<div class="title"><a class=" more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ng-class="{true: \'glyphicon glyphicon-minus\', false:\'glyphicon glyphicon-plus\'}[showMe]"  data-ng-click="toggle()"></a>{{title}}</div>' +
            '<div class="body" data-ng-show="showMe" data-ng-transclude=""></div>'+
            '</div>',
```

Comment: Hello
it shows me an error when I add this statement I think it does not accept ratings (' ');

Comment: Hello marcus , thank in advance for you help ,
I added (\) he put this mistake to me:
Syntax Error: Token '?' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 10 of the expression [{] starting at [{4}].

Comment: i remouved the ? expression and i replaced it with true i he don't works :(

Comment: Mercus thank you very much he work nice  thank you very much for your help

Comment: just another question please how i can fix the color of  accordion active when i click

Comment: @sani Ok, so if the NgClass which I provided works. please accept answer

Comment: Marcus , can i tchat with you please

Comment: @sani there is a check sign on the left side of my answer, press that :) It will be green when its pressed

Comment: i can not create the tchat because i have just one reputation :) can you invite me please

Comment: @sani great! just a moment. searching for how to create a chat

Comment: @sani can you reach this https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165626/angularjs-question-chat

Comment: he make to me You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here

Comment: can i  speak here

Comment: Marcus can i open a new ticket?

Comment: @sani Ok, then the best thing is to open a new question :)

Comment: yes marcus i opened a nuew question can i view them please

Comment: hy marcus how are you

Comment: can i speak with you :)